# .net c# windows forms, play sound without overlaping

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, audio

I am using  the current code to play a background music e sounds for the buttons click;

```
private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;            //Colocar A janela em FullScreen
                SoundPlayer music = new SoundPlayer(@"D:\Escola\Licenciatura\4º Ano\1º Semestre\Progig\Projeto\beyblade\Assets\Sounds\soundtrack.wav");
                music.Play();
            }
            private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SoundPlayer soundclick = new SoundPlayer(@"D:\Escola\Licenciatura\4º Ano\1º Semestre\Progig\Projeto\beyblade\Assets\Sounds\click.mp3");
                soundclick.Play();
            }
```

The song plays when the form loads, but when I click on a sound the background music stops and plays the sound from the click, is not there a way to keep both?

Comment: Application is terminated with `Application.Exit();` exactly after clicking the button?

Comment: Wrong example, in this case yes, but thats not the problem, I copied the wrong button, but changed it now.